# Hiding list item in angular ionic repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a list control where the user can filter the data. The list control has 4 levels with multiple items. By default the first level item appear only. Once the user clicks the first level, the second is shown and the first is hidden. The user can then click on the second level, in which case the third level will appear and hiding the second one etc..

When I select the first level, then all other first levels need to be hidden as well. Right now when I select the first level then the second appears for all first level items. Once the first level has been selected all other first levels need to be hidden, because the user is going to filter within the first level he selected. In the plunkr below, you will see two departments, if I select "Men", the "Womens" section should be hidden.

The hierarchy is:

Department -> Product Type -> Style -> Color Size Combination

The JSON is already structured in this way:

```
[
   {
      "departmentName":"Womens",
      "productTypes":[
         {
            "name":"Standard",
            "styles":[
               {
                  "name":"2001",
                  "details":[
                     {
                        "color":"blue",
                        "size":"m",
                        "productNum":1234567891212
                     },
                     {
                        "color":"blue",
                        "size":"x",
                        "productNum":1234567891212
                     },
                     {
                        "color":"blue",
                        "size":"xxl",
                        "productNum":1234567891212
                     },
                     {
                        "color":"blue",
                        "size":"s",
                        "productNum":1234567891212
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "departmentName":"Men",
      "productTypes":[
         {
            "name":"Standard",
            "styles":[
               {
                  "name":"2001Men",
                  "details":[
                     {
                        "color":"green",
                        "size":"m",
                        "productNum":1234567891212
                     },
                     {
                        "color":"green",
                        "size":"x",
                        "productNum":1234567891212
                     },
                     {
                        "color":"green",
                        "size":"xxl",
                        "productNum":1234567891212
                     },
                     {
                        "color":"green",
                        "size":"s",
                        "productNum":1234567891212
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='todo'>
  <ion-pane>

    <ion-content>
      <div class="container padding" style="background-color: #fff;" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col col-100">
            <span ng-repeat="f in filter">
              {{f}}&nbsp;<i class="icon ion-ios-close-empty"></i>
              &nbsp;<i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-thin-right" ng-show="$index < (filter.length-1)"></i>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list" ng-repeat="item in filterData">
          <div class="item item-divider" ng-click="setFilter(item.departmentName, 1);" ng-show="showDepartments">
            {{item.departmentName}}
          </div>
          <div ng-repeat="pt in item.productTypes">
            <div class="item item-divider" ng-click="setFilter(pt.name, 2);" ng-show="showProductTypes">
              {{pt.name}}
            </div>
            <div ng-repeat="style in pt.styles">
              <div class="item item-divider" ng-click="setFilter(style.name, 3);" ng-show="showStyles">
                {{style.name}}
              </div>
              <div ng-repeat="styleLine in style.details">
                <div class="item item-divider" ng-click="setFilter(styleLine, 4);" ng-show="showStyleDetails">
                  {{styleLine.color}} - {{styleLine.size}}
                  <br/> {{styleLine.productNum}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
</body>

</html>
```

And the JS:

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.filter = [];
  $scope.showDepartments = true;
  $scope.showProductTypes = false;
  $scope.showStyles = false;
  $scope.showStyleDetails = false;

  $scope.setFilter = function(filterValue, level) {
    if (level != 4) {
      $scope.filter[$scope.filter.length] = filterValue;
    } else {
      $scope.filter[$scope.filter.length] = filterValue.color;
      $scope.filter[$scope.filter.length] = filterValue.size;
    }
    if (level == 1) {
      $scope.showDepartments = false;
      $scope.showProductTypes = true;
    }
    if (level == 2) {
      $scope.showProductTypes = false;
      $scope.showStyles = true;
    }
    if (level == 3) {
      $scope.showStyles = false;
      $scope.showStyleDetails = true;
    }
    if (level == 4) {
      $scope.showStyleDetails = false;
    }
  }

  $scope.title = 'Ionic';
  $scope.filterData = [{
    "departmentName": "Womens",
    "productTypes": [{
      "name": "Standard",
      "styles": [{
        "name": "2001",
        "details": [{
          "color": "blue",
          "size": "m",
          "productNum": 1234567891212
        }, {
          "color": "blue",
          "size": "x",
          "productNum": 1234567891212
        }, {
          "color": "blue",
          "size": "xxl",
          "productNum": 1234567891212
        }, {
          "color": "blue",
          "size": "s",
          "productNum": 1234567891212
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "departmentName": "Men",
    "productTypes": [{
      "name": "Standard",
      "styles": [{
        "name": "2001Men",
        "details": [{
          "color": "green",
          "size": "m",
          "productNum": 1234567891212
        }, {
          "color": "green",
          "size": "x",
          "productNum": 1234567891212
        }, {
          "color": "green",
          "size": "xxl",
          "productNum": 1234567891212
        }, {
          "color": "green",
          "size": "s",
          "productNum": 1234567891212
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }];
})
```

And finally the plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/6YdnId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. I have used a property on the item itself to hide the first level for all items except the selected item. I have updated the plunkr. Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a filter factory and aplly to your ng-repeat https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: Not sure how this would helped with my outlined issue.

Comment: Its a most correct way to filter data tha n use a controller method